# .htaccess REWRITE ONLY if path contain NUMBERS and LETTERS

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I use .htaccess to hide GET variables on my website URL like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([A-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?music=$1 [NC,L]
```

The only variable I can GET is a unique ID containing letters and numbers. So I would like to create a rule to check if the GET variable contains letters and numbers.

What I would like:

```
http://www.website.com/123456ABCDEF > http://www.website.com/index.php?var=123456ABCDEF
```

What I don't want:

```
http://www.website.com/123456 > http://www.website.com/index.php?var=123456
http://www.website.com/ABCDEF > http://www.website.com/index.php?var=ABCDEF
```

Any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can tweak the regex:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^((?!(?:[A-Z]+|[0-9]+)$)[0-9A-Z]+)$ index.php?music=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

This will allow:

- `/abc123`
- `/987xyz`

But it won't allow:

- `/hello`
- `/777`

**Update:** It based on this comment from OP:

> `What if I want to check if one particular word is in the URL value ? For example, I want to apply this rule, only if there is the word "version" in the value.`

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} version [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!(?:[A-Z]+|[0-9]+)$)[0-9A-Z]{13,})$ index.php?music=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply too but it doesn't works. I tried the URL 'www.website.com/hello' (there is no numbers in the value so I don't want any redirect) but the htaccess still redirect me to 'www.website.com/index.php?var=hello'...

Comment: Works great! Thank you very much (I can not vote for your answer, not enough reputation ;) What if I want to check if one particular word is in the URL value ? For example, I want to apply this rule, only if there is the word "version" in the value. Any ideas?

Comment: Super! Thanks a lot for your help, one last thing, what if I want to check the length of the value. For example I want to check the value only if the length is >=13. There is a way do this? Is it something like {>=13} ? Thanks again.

Comment: Yes length check can be done through regex, check the updated answer now.

Comment: What does the `?:` signify? I've been looking and looking on the net but can't find reference to this combination, cheers

Comment: `(?:...)` is non capturing group

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/([A-Z]+|[0-9]+)/?$
RewriteRule ^([0-9A-Z]+)/?$ index.php?var=$1 [L,NC]
```

This will only route IDs to the `index.php` file if the ID contains *both* numbers and letters.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but it doesn't works. I uploaded your code, after I tried the URL 'www.website.com/hello' (there is no numbers in the value so I don't want any redirect) but the htaccess redirect me to 'www.website.com/index.php?var=hello'